# Querying through an association

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I've got an ecto query of the form:

```
  def query_clicks(user, freq \\ "day", filters \\ []) do
    from(Click)
    |> select(
      [c],
      [
        fragment("date_trunc(?,?) as t", ^freq, c.inserted_at), count(c.link_id) ]
      )
    # |> where([c], c.user.id == 1) # Didn't work
    |> where([c], ^filters)
    |> group_by([c], fragment("t"))
    |> Repo.all
  end
```

`Click` has an association:

```
has_one :user, through: [:link, :user]
```

What I'm trying to do is get the user's clicks, (what would be user.clicks in rails). How would I do that?

I'm using Phoenix 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more readable to start from the `user` and then go through [`assoc/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/3.0.7/Ecto.html#assoc/2):

```
user
|> assoc(:clicks)
|> select(
  [c],
  [
    fragment("date_trunc(?,?) as t", ^freq, c.inserted_at), count(c.link_id) ]
  )
|> where([c], ^filters)
|> group_by([c], fragment("t"))
|> Repo.all()
```

Assuming, of course, you have the correct associations in place in your `User` schema, which I'm guessing would be:

```
has_many :links, Link
has_many :clicks, through: [:links, :clicks]
```

As well as adding the correspondent `has_many :clicks` to your `Link` schema.

But you could also start from `Click` like you're doing:

```
Click
|> join(:inner, [c], l in Link, on: c.link_id == l.id and l.user_id == ^user.id)
...
```